# How to delete a specific row from azure mobile service table using Android?

Tags: java, android, azure

I am new to Android and Window Azure.I have created a database in Azure and some Tables.now I successfully inserted data to the table but now I want to delete a row from that table.I have tried the following code but its not working and the amulater gets hing .Please help me to solve this problem

```
//code use for delete.
del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final MobileServiceTable<Test> mtest;
        mtest=mClient.getTable(Test.class);
        try {
            final MobileServiceList<Test>res=mtest.where().field("fullname").eq("hanan").execute().get();
            mtest.delete("res");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

In the above code I just tried to delete the row whose `fullname field =="hanan"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Moblie Service with SQL database as a backend server, there are 2 ways to delete an item form table referred on o[fficial guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#deleting)

A, `mTable.delete(item)`

B, `mTable.delete(IDString)`

However, in your code:

> `mtest.delete("res");`

you used a string in delete function, Azure will delete the row with id field equl “res”.